# Spool to file in prolog

Tags: logging, swi-prolog, spool

I'm used to working with Oracle PL/SQL where spooling to files from the command line interface is a common task. Does such a feature exist within SWI-Prolog?

For example, if I were to interact with the command line SWI-Prolog in this way:

```
- cd prolog
- pl
?- [likes]
%likes compiled 0.00 sec, 4,792 bytes
true.
?- SPOOL_ON_COMMAND C:\temp.txt
true.
?- likes(sam, spaghetti).
true
?- likes(sam, italian).
false
?- SPOOL_OFF_COMMAND
true.
EOF: halt
```

I would expect my file at C:\temp.txt to contain:

```
?- likes(sam, spaghetti).
true
?- likes(sam, italian).
false
```

Comment: Check out this [link](http://www.ifcomputer.co.jp/en/manuals5.2/uguide/node27.html) it might help you!

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog, it's `protocol/1` (documented [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=protocol))